# Adding a Popover Follow Cursor to a React Pie Chart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pie-chart, popover, react-state

I am writing a react program to generate a dynamic pie chart based off of the answers to given questions. The base of the code was largely borrowed from [this project:](https://github.com/ruvictor/dynamic-pie-chart-react)
I modified it to include 28 questions and the user responds to the question based on a slider component from 0 to 100. Based on those numbers a pie chart with 28 slices will be filled in. I want the question to pop up when the user hovers of the slice of the pie chart that corresponds to that question. This is because the questions and the pie chart are on a different page, so I want the user to be able to easily see what question they responded to that resulted in each particular slice.

I tried using the React Suite Popover Follow Cursor, and it worked almost correctly but I had multiple bugs. I got the code for the Popover from [here:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-suite-popover-follow-cursor/)
Here is the code that I am currently trying:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css";
import { Button, Popover, Whisper } from "rsuite";


const Slice = (props) => {
  let slices = Object.keys(props.slices).map((sliceKey, i) => {
    const slice = props.slices[sliceKey];

    const gradientId = `gradient-${sliceKey}`;
    const lighterColor = getLighterColor(slice.fill, 100, slice.transform); // Adjust the percentage as needed

    return (
      <g key={sliceKey} transform={slice.rotate} >
        <defs>
          <radialGradient id={gradientId}>
            <stop offset="0%" stopColor={lighterColor} />
            <stop offset="100%" stopColor={slice.fill} />
          </radialGradient>
        </defs>

        <Whisper followCursor speaker={<Popover>{slice.question}</Popover>}>
          <g mask="url(#wedge-mask)">
            <circle
              className="Slice"
              cx="220"
              cy="220"
              r="200"
              fill={`url(#${gradientId})`}
              style={{ transform: `scale(${slice.transform})` }}
            ></circle>
          </g>
        </Whisper>
      </g>
    );
  });

  return <>{slices}</>;
};


// Helper function to get a lighter shade of a given color
const getLighterColor = (color, percentage, transform) => {
  const decColor = parseInt(color.substr(1), 16);
  const r = (decColor >> 16) & 255;
  const g = (decColor >> 8) & 255;
  const b = decColor & 255;

  const lighterR = Math.round(r + (255 - r) * (percentage / 100));
  const lighterG = Math.round(g + (255 - g) * (percentage / 100));
  const lighterB = Math.round(b + (255 - b) * (percentage / 100));

  return `rgb(${lighterR}, ${lighterG}, ${lighterB})`;
};

export default Slice;
```

## The props.slices object looks like this:

```
slices1: [
      {
        question: "I practice mindful breathing regularly",
        title: "SELF ASSESSMENT",
        rotate: "rotate(12.8571, 220, 220)",
        fill: "#FF5C00",
        transform: "0.01",
      },
      {
        question:
          "I recognize the mind-body-emotion connection in my own life.",
        title: "",
        rotate: "rotate(25.7142, 220, 220)",
        fill: "#FF5C00",
        transform: "0.01",
      },

      ...
]
```

## the value transform is then updated by the code for the questions page. I'm not sure if it would be useful, but here is the Pie Chart component that calls the slice.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Pie.css";
import Slice from "../Slice/Slice.js";

function Pie(props) {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="ChartBlock">
        <div className="ChartPie" style={{ width: "400px" }}>
          <svg
            className="ChartPieChunk"
            width="100%" // Adjust the width to accommodate the labels
            height="100%" // Adjust the height to accommodate the labels
            viewBox="0 0 440 440" // Adjust the viewBox for a larger area
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <defs>
              <g id="overlay">
                <rect x="219" y="20" height="200" width="2" fill="#FFF"></rect>
                <g transform="translate(210, 30)">
                  <path fill="#000"></path>
                </g>
              </g>
            </defs>
            <mask id="wedge-mask" fill="white">
              <path
                transform="translate(20, 20)"
                d="M93 7.241a200.006 200.006 0 0107.551-.865L200.004 200 48.97 20.241z"
                fillRule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </mask>
            <circle
              cx="220"
              cy="220"
              r="200"
              fill="#EFEFEF"
              stroke="#E3E3E3"
              strokeWidth="1"
            ></circle>
            <Slice slices={props.slices} />

            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(75.5, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(127, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(178.5, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(230, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(281, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(333, 220, 220)"></use>
            <use xlinkHref="#overlay" transform="rotate(384, 220, 220)"></use>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pie;
```

What i was expecting, was the popup to change according to which slice it was hovering over.[Pie Chart Bug Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Chv.png)To my understanding, rather than the pop up changing when the cusor moved slices, it seemed to change based on the radius of each slice. For example, when the cursor was at the edge of the pie chart, no matter what slice, it showed a pop up of the highest scored question, but closer to the center of the chart, regardless of slice, it showed the pop up for the lowest scored question.

I'm believe that React Suite is working correctly as intended, but that I am not implementing it correctly, probably because I pulled most of the code from someone elses project. However, I am unsure how to move forward, whether it is with React Suite or something else.